# Linux domain - central auth and laptops with cred caching

Tags: linux, domain, authentication, kerberos

I need to set up a linux network: central authentication server and laptops (maybe desktops). Laptops must cache credentials. What is the current best way to do that? Can kerberos be coerced into doing that? Should I install Samba WAD equivalent and use likewise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux server *and* clients? LDAP + kerberos would be the canonical answer. Take a look at [pam_ccreds](http://www.padl.com/OSS/pam_ccreds.html) or Fedora's [SSSD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SSSD) for caching authentication.

Comment: Good suggestions!